# Confusion with admob change?

Tags: android, admob

admob has some popup when i enter the console about admob legacy stopping. Im not sure what exactly admob legacy is. I have ads in all of our apps on google play. Im just trying to get some insight as to if it is necessary for me to make changes to code or if ads will still run after august 31st, im just trying to be 100% on whats going on.

if you can explain what is going on id be very appreciative, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob legacy is the old admob website (admob.com) while the new admob is apps.admob.com.

You are supposed to upgrade your account to the new admob.

You don't have to make changes to your existing apps on the play store.

However, from 1st August, 2014, for updates or new apps using ads to be accepted on the play store, they must use an advertising ID. In admob, this is only available via the google play services library and not the deprecated GoogleAdmobADSSdk-6.X.X.jar so you within your apps make sure you use admob via the google play service library.

Summary: Upgrade account to new admob(apps.admob.com) before 1st September, and use admob via google play services for new or updated apps from 1st August.

According to Eric (Google Admob developer engineer):

"As long as you've upgraded your AdMob account by the August 31 deadline, ads will continue to serve, even through the old AdMob SDK.

The SDK upgrade deadline on August 1st per the Google Play Ad Policy just means you can't update apps to the Google Play store that include the old AdMob SDK. As far as the legacy AdMob site shutdown, you need to upgrade to the new AdMob site to still get impressions. Once you upgrade, AdMob makes a link between your legacy ad unit to your new AdMob ad unit. So requests even on that legacy ad unit can continue to serve because that link is made. If you fail to update to the new site, there is no such link, and your requests will no longer fill after August 31 (regardless if you are using the old AdMob SDK or Google Play services)."

More [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/2IgChJZ0w8I)

Comment: i completely understand now, thanks for your time, really i was getting all bugged out :)

Comment: I just checked and im not getting any impressions or any adds at all since January 2017 they all stopped. Was there another change or a quick fix this time? any idea?